# While using Autocomplete Extender my Browser hangs Up and message arrives UnRepesonsive Script

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocompleteextender

I have Around more than 1000 Records in my dataset and when i search using AJAX autocomplete extender my browser hangs up and message is displayed Unresponsive Script(Close/Stop Script)

What to do to fetch records without being hanged up.

Comment: Please post a sample of your code around where this issue is occurring.

Comment: aspx page<textbox/><autocompleteextender/> code behind webservice and sql query thats it